# Authorize.net recurring billing Silent Post URL Setup

Tags: payment-gateway, authorize.net, silent-post

I have implemented Authorize.net's ARB for Recurring Billing. I found Silent Post settings where i can set callback url for handling payment or subscription status.
But here is no clear documention how to implement it. Depending on those status i want to downgrade or upgrade my users.How can i know when the card will expire, or when is the next billing date? So i could notify user that on Date xx-xx-xx your card will be charged.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using Silent Post as it has been deprecated in favor of [Webhooks](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/webhooks.html) and will eventually go away.

Silent Post won't tell you details about the subscription because that is not what it is designed to do. It only tells you when a transaction is processed (e.g. a credit card is charged) and details about that transaction.

Currently it is not possible to get the expiration date of the credit card or the next billing date from the Authorize.Net API. You can get the status of a subscription which will tell you if the card is active or expired but that won't tell you when the card will expire if it hasn't already done so.

If this information is important to you your application will need to keep track of it. When you create the subscription you should capture the expiration date and the billing cycle. Then you don't need to make any API calls or depend on Silent Post or Webhooks to check on this information.